# Not able to Mount External HDD on Linux

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have been using Windows 7 since long and after my laptop's motherboard has gone faulty I decided to purchase a laptop. As I had enough personal data in my HDD I converted my Laptop's internal HDD into an external HDD.

It has been working fine with all the windows laptop and after purchasing a new laptop I used it with linux which was OK with it as it was working fine.

After couple of days I received a pop-up while inserting HDD that it cannot be mounted as an action I tried same with a windows laptop and I wasnt able to use in it. But in windows I was able to recover 1 drive out of 5 drives from my HDD which I can use in Linux as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the error on the popup say? Can you post the image somewhere else and give us a link here ?

Comment: Please drop me an email at singh.ankit.05@gmail.com I will fwd u screenshot. I tried to attach screenshot in the query but due to limitation of some credits I wasnt able to do so.

Comment: http://s3.postimg.org/syh3ql32b/Screenshot_from_2014_10_19_09_08_31.png

Comment: http://s8.postimg.org/qben6xepx/Ankit.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you attaching the HDD to your computer via usb or Sata?
do
Sudo lsusb 
and see if it is even reading the device if not you have corrupted sectors for recovery I suggest Hirens Boot Disc and the seagate FBI standard HD recovery tool.

Comment: I am attaching it via USB only and it can trace one of the 5 drives from HDD. So power is available and accordingly they are in sync but other 4 drives are not accessible